# linprog - "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch" error

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

"Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.' when running a linprog coding.

My code is

```
for M = 1 : size(PV_output,1)
for N = 1 : size(WT_output,2)


    f(:,M:N ) = [((CRF*CC_PV(M)/PVenergy(M)+OM_PV)); ((CRF*CC_WT(N))/WTenergy(N))+OM_WT];  % Objective function coefficients

    %A(:,:) = [-PV_output(:,:,K)  -WT_output(:,:,L)];
    A (:,M,N) = [-PV_output(:,M)  -WT_output(:,N) ];

    b(:,:)  = -Demand(:);

    lb = zeros(2,1);

    ub = [max_PV_area/PV_area; max_WT_area/WT_area]';

end
end 
[x, fval, exitflag] = linprog(f,A,b,[],[],lb,ub)
```

PV_output is 8760x1x27 and WT_output is 8760x1x3

I am trying to find the "f" coefficients below for all the combinations of the 27 and 3 PV and WT's in this code
Does anyone know how to index the "f" to do so?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem is that you need to get size of the third dimension of the matrices:

```
for M = 1 : size(PV_output,3) %# <---3, not 1  
    for N = 1 : size(WT_output,3) %# <---3, not 1
```

Next, you don't want `(:,M:N)` but rather `(:,M,N)`

```
f(:,M,N)
```

There is likely more. This should get you started; and use the debugger to see what sizes the dimensions of your matrices are, and make sure they are what you think they should be.  For example, you can't add matrices of different sizes together, so make sure the dimensions are the same.

Comment: I have tried this code as suggested - When I check the size of f it is 2x1. I believe it should be 2x1x81 where the 81 represents all the combinations (27*3) that can be made? I still get an error on the line where "A" is written (Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
) when trying the format A (:,M,N)